# How to rotate only the right or left part of an image

Tags: qml, qtquick2, qt-quick

I want to simulate the closure of one page of a book.
Any suggestions on how to do that in qml?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Perhaps [`Flipable`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-flipable.html), in combination with the [`fillMode`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-image.html#fillMode-prop) property of `Image`:

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import QtQuick.Window 2.0

Window {
    id: window
    width: 640
    height: 480
    visible: true

    Image {
        id: backgroundImage
        source: "http://www.thebookdesigner.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/04/pages-vs-spreads.png"
        anchors.centerIn: parent

        Flipable {
            id: flipable
            anchors.fill: parent
            anchors.leftMargin: parent.width / 2

            property bool flipped: false

            front: Image {
                id: foldImage
                source: backgroundImage.source
                fillMode: Image.Pad
                width: foldImage.implicitWidth / 2
                horizontalAlignment: Image.AlignRight
            }

            back: Image {
                source: backgroundImage.source
                width: foldImage.implicitWidth / 2
                fillMode: Image.Pad
                horizontalAlignment: Image.AlignLeft
            }

            transform: Rotation {
                id: rotation
                origin.x: 0
                origin.y: flipable.height / 2
                axis.x: 0; axis.y: 1; axis.z: 0 // set axis.y to 1 to rotate around y-axis
                angle: 0 // the default angle
            }

            states: State {
                name: "back"
                PropertyChanges {
                    target: rotation;
                    angle: -180
                }
                when: flipable.flipped
            }

            transitions: Transition {
                NumberAnimation {
                    target: rotation
                    property: "angle"
                    duration: 1000
                    easing.type: Easing.InCubic
                }
            }

            MouseArea {
                anchors.fill: parent
                onClicked: flipable.flipped = !flipable.flipped
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image: Flipable book]

`Flipable` does what its name suggests, and the `fillMode` property in combination with a `width` that is too small for the entire image allows you to "reposition" the contents of the image within the bounds of the item.

So, the `front` item contains the right side of the image, and the `back` item contains the left side. With an actual book that has many pages, you'd have to use the relevant pages instead of the same one.